# plotting multiple stacked bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I have the following dataframe that counts the number of managers and non managers per sex in each Business Unit (it is a multiindex that sums the value of Male and Female that are manager or not in each Business Unit). It may happen, as you can see, that a Business Unit has only Non Manager or Manager as employees:

```
                                       Female  Male
Business Unit Professional Category              
South         Non Manager                37    45
West          Non Manager                31    37
East          Manager                    14    15
              Non Manager               342   412
Noth          Manager                     5     5
              Non Manager               457   550
Center        Non Manager                44    53
```

I wanted to create a stacked bar chart where in the x-axis I have the Professional Category (one bar for Manager and one separete bar for Non Manager) and in each of those bars the stacked amount of Male and Female. But I would need to repeat this same stacked bar graph for each of the regions: South, West, East, Noth, Center.

What would be the most elegant wat to display this information in matplotlib/seaborn?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 5, figsize=(20, 8))
iax = iter(ax.flatten())
for n, g in df.groupby('Business Unit'):
    g.loc[n, :].plot.bar(ax=next(iax), title=f'{n}', stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I needed, thanks! Do you happen to know how could I display the % of the total from Male and Female inside the stacked bar by any chance? Thanks again!